# Why my code is printing additional value when it is not present in the passing parameters

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6]
print(list(map(lambda a: print(a), zip(a, b, c))))
```

I am Getting :
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
[None, None, None, None]

Where does this [None, None, None, None] is coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

The tuples are displayed by `print(a)`. However, the array of `None`s is displayed by the first `print`. When using `map`, you are mapping `a` to the value **returned** by `print(a)`, not the one it **displays**. In Python, since `print` is a "void function", it is actually considered to return `None`. Hence your result.